# Difference among reference|color and color

Tags: android

I was wondering, is there any differences among

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<attr name="titleColor" format="reference|color" />

</resources>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<attr name="titleColor" format="color" />

</resources>
```

---

As either ways workable for the below 2 themes

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyDark" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="titleColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyDark" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="titleColor">@color/theColorReference</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you specify `reference|color` then you also set references as value additionally to color values. References can be any color in a values XML file or references to system colors...

Comment: according to this page, references are not the same as resources, they are to be seen as references to style attributes. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes